# What's the music that plays in the background in intense scenes in Sagrada Reset?

Tags: music, sagrada-reset

So there's this dramatic music that starts playing in the background during some intense moments of the show. I looked everywhere without being able to find it mostly since only the openings and endings are receiving all the attention. This one seems to be rather a theme song than anything else. I pinpointed some parts of the last episodes where the music is playing so someone can identify it.
It can be heard in episodes:

- Ep. 19 [6:21-6:52 & 21:13-21:56]
- Ep. 20 [16:14-20:26]
- Ep. 22 [2:51-4:07]
- Ep. 23 [7:42-9:42]

Answer (score -1):

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nr9V7DSA9I

Took some digging to find it, but here it is I believe.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "Sad Romance" by Ji Pyeong Kwon was used in *Sagrada Reset*. Searching any credits for this song/artist didn't give any result.

Comment: This is almost completely different other than the fact that both songs are played by violin and sort of have the same tone at some parts. The problem though isn't that it's a differen't song...neither it is that it's not even played in the series. The problem is that the song you suggested is the most regognisable sad song playing in Naruto. Thanks I guess for trying but sadly this isn't the one.